# Python Wordpress REST API returns False when passing an array as a value

Tags: python, wordpress, rest, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

decided to make a project that uses ACF(Wordpress), Wordpress REST API and Python.

I have a custom field type. Whenever I try to POST an array as a value, I get a JSON response with the response of False.

This custom field is a gallery, thus it has an array of links. It’s just that I cannot update that list but I can pass everything else(like strings).

I’m aware than the POST data should use JSON argument and I’ve tried it with other types of variables. I’m aware that the list needs to be passed as a string, but still no luck.

I’m using JWT as authorisation and my headers are:

```
curHeaders = {
“Authorization”: “Bearer %s” % jwt_token,
“Content-Type”: “application/json”,
“Accept”: “application/json”
}
```